# yii2 javascript is not working. how can i add javascript

Tags: javascript, php, yii2-advanced-app

in yii 1, i created special javaScript file and called it menu_navigate.js. And linked it using following code:

```
<script src="<?php echo Yii::app()->theme->baseUrl;?>/Index/menu_navigate.js"></script>
```

It worked. But, when i created yii 2 application and registered it into ThemeAsset by using following code:

```
 public $js = [

        'Index/menu_navigate.js',
```

]
also, i included following code in my Index.php page:

```
<?php

/* @var $this \yii\web\View */
/* @var $content string */

use frontend\assets\ThemeAsset;

ThemeAsset::register($this);

?>
```

it is not working. Does it exist any error?

Answer (score 0):

In yii2 you have to use registerJsFile method in order to call a javascript for example:

```
$this->registerJsFile('http://example.com/js/main.js', ['depends' => [\yii\web\JqueryAsset::className()]]);
```

for further information you can refer this link:
[link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-client-scripts.html)